# Animation Nodes Crashing and not loading properly again

Tags: animation-nodes

I was trying the animation nodes features, when I tried to render animation it crashed and, for my surprise, the whole node-set is red and "Undefined Socket" labelled.

[image: After-Crash]

Comment: make sure that the animation nodes addon is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons* and reenable *Animation Nodes* in the community tab, which was switched off for me after Blender crashed. If *Animation Nodes* is not there as an option, try reinstalling the add-on if you have the zip file.

Answer (score -1):

This is totally a bug that happened while rendering. This is probably not supposed to happen. Try closing blender and restarting your computer. If you are still facing this issue, try recreating the setup. I know it's hard to set it up again, but It is possible. I had to try 7 times just to simulate fire using materials and animating it, but the end result was great.

So don't give up and do what I have said. If it doesn't work, try at least 10 times. If it still doesn't work, I think you are using a version of blender that can't support this kind of stuff. (Which is highly unlikely). And a tip for using this site, don't put stuff or questions regarding the answer as an answer. You can comment on he question instead.